# Is this set dense in $H^1(\Omega)?$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Is $$V_1 = \{v \in H^1(\Omega) \;:\;f(v) = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega\}$$
dense in $H^1(\Omega)$ with the same norm as $H^1(\Omega)?$

Here $f$ is some linear functional so that $V_1$ is also Hilbert.

I don't know how to prove this. Maybe someone can sketch how to prove it for $f(v) = v$ (so $V_1 = H^1_0$) cause I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: What is $a$? Any function on the boundary? A constant?

Comment: @julien I changed the condition so that $V_1$ is Hilbert.

Comment: And what is $\Omega$? Any assumption of regularity of its boundary?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Let it have smooth boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This answer addresses the case $f(v)=v$.

I'm far from being an expert, so I've looked around and apparently, your $V_1$ makes sense in particular when **$\Omega$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $C^1$ boundary**. In this case, one can define the [trace operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_%28Sobolev_space%29)
$$
T:u\longmapsto u_{|\partial \Omega}
$$
on $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ functions by restriction to the boundary (it would not make sense on $H^1$ directly, as these functions are defined up to a measure zero set, and the boundary is such a set).

Wth the hypotheses above, we can prove that $T$ is bounded from $C^1(\overline{\Omega})$ to $L_2(\partial\Omega)$. So it can be extended by density to a continuous operator on $H_1$ and your **$V_1$ is the kernel of the trace  operator, usually denoted by $H^1_0(\Omega)$**.

By construction, **$H^1_0(\Omega)$ is closed in $H_1(\Omega)$** as the trace operator is continuous. Clearly, $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is not the whole of $H_1(\Omega)$, as it does not contain, for instance, the nonzero constant functions. So with the assumptions above, $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is **not dense** in $H_1(\Omega)$.

Comment: why is every $H^1$ function Lipschitz? What about $\log|\log x|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for example

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 I did everything as if it was $H^\infty$...Thanks.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Now it should be correct, no?

Comment: Why do you need Poincaré's inequality? Usually the estimate $||Tu||\leq ||u||_{H^1}$ does not require Poincaré's inequality. The main point should be to show, that $H^1_0$ is closed and this is due to the continuity of the trace operator.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 You're right, thanks.